# Gunicorn Service Environment File Format?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, environment-variables, gunicorn

I'm deploying a Django project on an ubuntu machine using gunicorn and nginx, following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) to do it.

I have a gunicorn service that looks like this, similar to the one in the tutorial:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/project/mysite
EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/projectenv/bin/postactivate
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/projectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 10 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/project/mysite.sock mysite.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Since, as I understand, the gunicorn service is run in a completely new environment instead of my project's virtual environment I need to find another way to pass it environment variables. I found [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/gunicorn-service-can-t-read-environment-variables) which says I can add an EnvironmentFile to my service file, which I did above.

I directed the environment file to my virtualenv's postactivate script, which looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is sourced after this virtualenv is activated.

export DJANGO_DEBUG=False
...
```

Which doesn't work, unsurprisingly.

**What is the correct format for this EnvironmentFile to be in?**

Comment: the environment file is for environment variables

Comment: Note that this is a question entirely about systemd; it has nothing to do with Django, Python or gunicorn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to pass something like:

```
DJANGO_DEBUG=False
PYTHON_PATH=:bla
```

documentation [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=)

Comment: So I need to create a file with this variables and use it in ```EnvironmentFile```?

Comment: exactly, give it a try :)